# Can model class implement Model UI?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So far in my Java code with Spring Boot I was using models, or POJO objects to achieve better control of my objects, etc. Usually I am creating Entities, Repositories, Services, Rest controllers, just like documentation and courses are suggesting.
Now however I am working with Thymeleaf templates, HTML a bit of Bootstrap and CSS in order to create browser interface. For methods in `@Controller`, as parameter, I am passing Model from Spring Model UI like this:

```
@GetMapping("/employees")
private String viewAllEmployees(Model employeeModel) {
    employeeModel.addAttribute("listEmployees", employeeService.getAllEmployees());
    return "employeeList";
}
```

My question is: How can I use my POJO objects instead of org.springframework.ui.Model;?

My first guess was this:

```
public class EmployeeModel implements Model{

private long employeeId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String phone;
private long companyId;
//getter and setter methods
}
```

And in order to do that I have to `@Override` Model methods which is fine with me. And it looks like Java, Spring etc. does not complain in compile time, and I can use this POJO object in my `@Controller` like this:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
@Autowired 
private EmployeeService employeeService;    
@GetMapping("/employees")
private String viewAllEmployees(EmployeeModel employeeModel) {
    employeeModel.addAttribute("listEmployees", employeeService.getAllEmployees());
    return "employeeList";
}}
```

I run the code and it starts, shows my /home endpoint which works cool, however when I want to go to my /employees endpoing where it should show my eployees list it throws this:

```
Method [private java.lang.String com.bojan.thyme.thymeApp.controller.EmployeeController.viewAllEmployees(com.bojan.thyme.thymeApp.model.EmployeeModel)] with argument values:[0] [type=org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap] [value={}] ] with root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

exception.

Please note that Rest controller is working perfectly in browser and Postman.

Is it possible that String as a method is the problem? Should my method be of some other type like `List<EmployeeModel>` or maybe `EmployeeModel`  itself? If it is so, how to tell the method that I want my employeeList.html to be returned?

I sincerely hope that someone can halp me with this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use my POJO objects instead of org.springframework.ui.Model;?

I don't think that is the best practice when you are working with Thymeleaf. According to their [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html), you should attach your Objects to your Model. So in your controller you would be manipulating models that contain your Pojos.

Example:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "message", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView messages() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("message/list");
        mav.addObject("messages", messageRepository.findAll());
        return mav;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always use `org.springframework.ui.Model` as argument. This class is basically a `Map` with key/value pairs that are made available to Thymeleaf for rendering.

Your first example is how you should do it:

```
@GetMapping("/employees") //<1>
private String viewAllEmployees(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employees", employeeService.getAllEmployees()); // <2>
    return "employeeList"; // <3>
}
```

- <1> This is the URL that the view will be rendered on
- <2> Add any Java object you want as attribute(s) to the model
- <3> Return the name of the Thymeleaf template. In a default Spring Boot with Thymeleaf application, this will refer to the template at `src/main/resources/templates/employeeList.html`. In that template, you will be able to access your model value with `${employees}`.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. So there is no way to use POJO objects with Thymeleaf, and I have to work with Entities.

Comment: @TavernaJoe Not sure what you mean exactly. You can add any kind of object as an attribute to the `Model`. So you can return POJO's from your `employeeService`, or you can convert the `Employee` entity to a `EmployeeDto` in your controller for example.